# No Ouput to DOM Tree

Tags: javascript, dom

In the following code, my attempts at creating the preparePlaceholder on the the fly
has failed, and the only error is "parent is not defined" from the error console.

I'm modifying this example for use with a JS object literal and could use the 
sage wisdom of StackOverflow.

TIA

```
imageGallery={

    // IDs
    placeHolderID:'placeholder',
    imageNavListID:'imagegallerylist',

    // CSS Classes

    init:function(){

        if(!document.getElementById || !document.createTextNode){return;}
        imageGallery.preparePlaceholder();// Call to preparePlacholder
        // Prepare Gallery:
        imageGallery.navList = document.getElementById(imageGallery.imageNavListID);
        if(!imageGallery.navList){return;}
        var links = imageGallery.navList.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(var i = 0; i<links.length;i++){
        links[i].onclick = function(){
        // Call to showPic function:    
        return imageGallery.showPic(this) ? false : true;
        }

      }


},


    showPic:function(whichpic){
        imageGallery.pHolder=document.getElementById(imageGallery.placeHolderID);
        if(!imageGallery.pHolder || imageGallery.pHolder.nodeName != "IMG"){return;}
        var source = whichpic.getAttribute("href");
        imageGallery.pHolder.setAttribute("src",source);
        if(document.getElementById("description")){
            // var text = whichpic.getAttribute("title");
            var text = whichpic.getAttribute("title") ? whichpic.getAttribute("title") : "";
            var description = document.getElementById("description");
            if(description.firstChild.nodeType == 3){
            description.firstChild.nodeValue = text;

            }

        }
        return true;

},

    preparePlaceholder:function(){
        var placeholder = document.createElement("img");
        placeholder.setAttribute("id", "placeholder");
        placeholder.setAttribute("src","images/placeholder.gif");
        placeholder.setAttribute("alt","My Image Gallery");
        // alert(placeholder);
        var description = document.createElement("p");
        description.setAttribute("id","description");
        var desctext = document.createTextNode("Choose an Image");
        description.appendChild(desctext);
        var gallery = document.getElementById("imageGallery");
        imageGallery.insertAfter(placeholder,imageGallery);
        imageGallery.insertAfter(description,imageGallery.placeholder);

        // alert("Function Called");
},

// Utility Functions
      insertAfter:function(newElement,targetElement){
        var parent = targetElement.parentNode;
        if(parent.lastChild == targetElement){
            parent.appendChild(newElement);

        } else {

            parent.insertBefore(newElement,targetElement.nextSibling);

        }

    },
    addLoadEvent:function(func){
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if(typeof window.onload != 'function'){
            window.onload = func;
        }else{
            window.onload = function(){
                oldonload();
                func();
            }

        }

    }

}   
// End Utility Functions    

imageGallery.addLoadEvent(imageGallery.init);   

// window.onload=imageGallery.init;


  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="uft-8" />
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="layout" charset="utf-8" />

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Snapshots</h1>
    <ul id="imagegallerylist">
    <!--Links Here-->
    </ul>   
<script src="scripts/imageGallery.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: First thing I've noticed in the code provided is `getElementById("imageGallery")` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Have an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nalum/vQs7w/) which doesn't produce errors. I have removed your comments and put in comments where I have changed the code.

JavaScript:

```
var gallery = document.getElementById("imageGallery");
// Changed from imageGallery to gallery
imageGallery.insertAfter(placeholder, gallery);
// Changed from imageGallery.placeholder to placeholder
imageGallery.insertAfter(description, placeholder);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="imageGallery"></div> <!-- Added this div -->
```

Comment: `code`      insertAfter:function(newElement,targetElement){
  var targetElement = document.getElementById('imagegallerylist');
  var parent = targetElement.parentNode;
  if(parent.lastChild == targetElement){
   parent.appendChild(newElement);
   
  } else {
   
   parent.insertBefore(newElement,targetElement.nextSibling);
   
  }
  
 },This also worked, but I'll try your solution and thanks for the JSFiddle connect. Created an account.

Comment: Should the order in the source code matter? Switched the position in the JS preventing the description from appearing above the placeholder `  //From StackOverFlow
  var gallery = document.getElementById("imageGallery");
  // Changed from imageGallery.placeholder to placeholder
  imageGallery.insertAfter(description, placeholder);
   // Changed from imageGallery to gallery
  imageGallery.insertAfter(placeholder, gallery);
  // End StackOverFlow`

Comment: Yes you will have to put the `placeholder` in before the `description`, unless you change how you do the insert.